# Using MapBasic Layout

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, vba

I'm trying to create a Layout window in Vb6 using MapInfo 2021 but the Layout function in this version seems to not be functioning as the older versions.

In MapInfo 10.5, a layout window could be created by the code:

```
m1 = new_winMap("Layout")
MapInfo.Do "Set Next Document Parent " & WinMaps(m1).hWnd & " Style 1"
MapInfo.RunMenuCommand 604
On Error Resume Next
MapInfo.Do " Set Layout Frame Contents On"
MapName = "Layout"

WinMaps(m1).Caption = WinMaps(m1).Caption + " " & MapWinID & " " & 
CLng(MapInfo.Eval("windowid(0)"))
WinMaps(m1).lblWinCaption.Caption = WinMaps(m1).Caption
WinMaps(m1).Tag = MapWinID & "*" & m1

If MapInfo.Eval("numwindows()") <> OldID Then
   WinMaps(m1).Show
   WinMaps(m1).lblMapName.Caption = MapName
End If
```

Which doesn't work in 2021 since the code 604 doesn't seem to work anymore.

Here's the updated code:

```
m1 = new_winMap("Layout")
MapInfo.Do "Set Next Document Parent " & WinMaps(m1).hWnd & " Style 1"
    
'Attempted calling it from mapbasic directly. Doesn't work.
'MapInfo.Do " Run Application """ & App.Path & "\Tools\Layout.MBX"""
                        
MapWinID = CLng(MapInfo.Eval("FrontWindow()"))
WindowIDTxt.Caption = MapWinID

MapInfo.RunMenuCommand 620
               
WinMaps(m1).Show
MapInfo.Do "Run Command ""Layout Designer"""
layoutID = CLng(MapInfo.Eval("FrontWindow()"))
MapInfo.Do "Set Coordsys Layout Units ""in"" Create Frame (0.2,0.2) (8.3,10.8)"
MapWinID = val(WindowIDTxt.Caption)
MapInfo.Do "Set Designer Frame Window " & layoutID & " ID 1 " & " From Window " & MapWinID & " Legends On"
MapInfo.Do "Set Layout Frame Contents On"
MapInfo.Do "Set Layout Frame Contents Active"
WinMaps(m1).Hide

MapName = "Layout"

WinMaps(m1).Caption = WinMaps(m1).Caption + " " & MapWinID & " " & CLng(MapInfo.Eval("windowid(0)"))
WinMaps(m1).lblWinCaption.Caption = WinMaps(m1).Caption
WinMaps(m1).Tag = MapWinID & "*" & m1

If MapInfo.Eval("numwindows()") <> OldID Then
    WinMaps(m1).Show
    WinMaps(m1).lblMapName.Caption = MapName
    Call AddToWindowList(WinMaps(m1).Caption)
End If
```

Notably using either 604 or 620 results in an empty layout.

Using this code:

```
Include "mapbasic.def"

Dim i_map_id As Integer
Dim frameID As Integer
Dim layoutID As Integer

i_map_id = FrontWindow()

Run Command "Layout Designer"
layoutID = FrontWindow()
Set Coordsys Layout Units "in" Create Frame (0.2,0.2) (8.3,10.8) Name "Layout" 

Set Designer Frame
    Window layoutID
    ID 1
    From Window i_map_id
    Legends On
```

Directly on MapInfo 2021 as an .mbx file creates a frame of the current map on a layout but using it on vb6 just results in an empty layout.

I've also seen a mention of a 'Classic Layout' in the Documentation but it doesn't show any clue or any info about that.

Here's what it looks like directly calling it in MapInfo:

[image: MapInfoLayout]

and here's what it looks like calling it in Vb6.

[image: Vb6Layout]

Comment: Looking at your new code, it seems you create two layout designer windows: One using Run Menu Command 620 and another using Run Command "Layout Designer". Then you add a frame to the second layout designer and try to embed a map into this frame. But I think the ID MapWinID refers back to your first layout designer window? Did I overlook or misunderstand something?

Comment: I already tried omitting either commands and running both options respectively. Neither makes a difference. Both creates an empty layout.

Comment: Can you try adding a new map with just one layer to see if that's allowed: "Map From SomeTableName Into Window LayoutID"

Comment: Still empty, unfortunately.

Also made a discovery, that most of the code I tried worked on the same vb6 application (with the same code) but connected to the older version of MapInfo (10.5). Still no idea why this one won't but the issue is probably in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Menu Command ID for the new Layout Designer window:

```
Define M_WINDOW_LAYOUT_DESIGNER                620
```

Be aware that there also have been some changes to the way you add elements to the Layout Designer window compared to the way you did it with the classic Layout window.

You would typically have an empty frame and insert a map into this. Often I would use an existing map and refer to this:

```
Set Designer Frame
    Window nLayoutID
    ID nMapFrameID
    From Window nMID
```

where nLayoutID is the Window ID of the layout Designer window, nMapFrameID is the ID of the frame you want to map inserted into and nMID is the existing Map Window you want to be cloned and inserted into the empty frame.

Also keep in mind that with the new Layout Designer, the embedded maps are standalone and no longer referring to another map.

Comment: I tried implementing the Set Designer Frame into my code but the Layout created still remained empty even though the code seemed to connect to the map as running the code with breakpoints causes the original map responds to the layout window, stretching and shrinking with it. This does not happen if the code is run normally.

Comment: Can you add your changed code to the initial question?

Comment: Updated the code. Also added images for visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest asking on their old, but still active forum here. They have a new one but I don't use it.
https://groups.google.com/g/mapinfo-l?pli=1

Comment: The new one that Ross refers to is the Precisely Knowledge Community: https://community.precisely.com/communities/community-home?communitykey=fe4d1ee2-f1c6-4307-87d2-00bea1344885